# Игнор атрибута required

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая создает форму по нажатию на кнопку и вставляет ее поверх страницы. Сама вставка работает четко, но проблема заключается в следующем, функция создает вот такое поле с атрибутами:

```
var InputNameProduct = document.createElement('input');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute('type', 'text');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Назва продукту');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute('name', 'name_product');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute("required", "required");
InputNameProduct.style.fontSize = '20px';
```

Все атрибуты вставлены успешно, однако если это поле оставить пустым и отправить форму, то required не срабатывает. Поясните пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

Comment: "*required не срабатывает*"  --- Это неправда..................... Приведите полный js код и  html.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне всё работает.

```js
var InputNameProduct = document.createElement('input');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute('type', 'text');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Назва продукту');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute('name', 'name_product');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute('autocomplete','off');
InputNameProduct.setAttribute("required", "required");
InputNameProduct.style.fontSize = '20px';

document.getElementById('testy').append(InputNameProduct);
```

```html
<form id="testy">
  <button>test</button>
</form>
```